# Cannot align checkbox in table to the left

Tags: html, css

I have a checkbox in a table and I cannot align them to the left.

```
<tr>
<td colspan="3" class="cb">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="checked" /> this is a checkbox
</td>
</tr>


table.all td.cb{
color: #424242;
border:1px solid black;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:left;
}
```

I have tried many things, but the result is this:

[image]

I applied a border for demonstration purposes.

If I add float:left, I get this:

[image]

I used the same code in another webpage where it was working fine (there the table had 2 columns only).

**Solution**:

I already had this in my .css file which strangely caused the problem in spite of the colspan="3"

```
table.all td input{
width:90%;
float:left;
}
```

I changed it to

```
table.all td input.i{
width:90%;
float:left;
}
```

and added a class="i" to all the other input types and now it's working fine.

The whole form if necessary:

```
<div id="container_center">
            <form>
                <table class="minden">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <p class="title">Create new account</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <p class="title2">Enter account holder information</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <div id="container_jobb_content_vonal"> </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>First name: *</p>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <p>Last name: *</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" size="45">
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="text" name="lastname" size="45">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>Email: *</p>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <p>Email again: *</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="email" size="45">
                        </td>   

                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="text" name="email2" size="45">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>Address 1: *</p>
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <p>Address 2:</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="address1" size="45">
                        </td>

                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="text" name="address2" size="45">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>Country: *</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select name="country" class="sel_country">
                                <option value="">[Please Select]</option>
                                <option value="United States">United States</option>
                                <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                                <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>City: *</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>State/Province: *</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>Zip code: *</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="city" size="45">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="state" size="30">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="zip" size="10" class="zip">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>Phone number: *</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="phone" size="45">
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <p class="title3">Create your login</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <div id="container_jobb_content_vonal"> </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>Username: *</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="username" size="45">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>Password: *</p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>Confirm password: *</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="password" size="45">
                        </td>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input type="text" name="password2" size="45">
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <p class="title3">Accept terms</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">
                            <div id="container_jobb_content_vonal"> </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" class="cb">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="checked"/>this is a checkbox
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="termsofservice.html">Terms of service</a></li>
                                <li><a href="privacypolicy.html">Privacy policy</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="submit" colspan="3">
                            <input type="submit" name="purchase" value="Purchase" id="submitbutton"> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>


            </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should put whole of your code (`that is relevant`), because it's working fine for me in IE,Chrome,Opera,Safari,Firefox.

Comment: Well, not *all* of the code please, only the code *relevant* to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Looks like your checkbox is inheriting width/padding from some parent. Did you try doing float:left to the td or to the checkbox?

Comment: could you set this for jsfiddler. B'cos your code is working fine.May be some inheritance styles troubles you.Put whole thing on jsfiddler.

Comment: Believe me , It's working well, here is the proof: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/KcvZJ/)

Comment: Thanks guys! Now I know what caused the problem but I still need help to solve it. I updated my question.

Comment: @erdomester What is the class of parent `table` (`table` that includes this `tr`) ?

Comment: @ Siamak.A.M please add some solution (or mine) as you were the first to comment and lead me to find the cause.

Comment: @erdomester did my answer solve your problem ?

Comment: nice and elegant solution, really useful

Answer (score 7):

You could also accomplish this by excluding the checkbox from your input style.  For example, I was encountering a similar problem with this CSS:

```
        input {
        width: 300;
    }
```

And fixed by changing to this:

```
        input:not([type="checkbox"]) {
        width: 300;
    }
```